# Can i call/request a .net handler (ashx) using javascript?

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, handler

Is it possible to call a handler using javascript code? e.g. i have a handler deployed at this location http://mysitename.com/getMyData.ashx. Can I call this handler or just request it using javascript? Is it even possible or not? Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes you can

use ajax or jquery ajaxcall for this.

same ajax function :

```
function showHint(elementid,url,str) {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById(elementid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: what should i put in the str variable ??? i have put the url http://mysitename.com/getMyData.ashx in the url variable.

Comment: you can pass emptystring if you dont want to pass any query string data

Comment: actually i did pass an empty string but i thnk this statement is not being executed:

  document.getElementById(elementid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

I even placed an alert statement here which didnt work. What could be the issue?

Comment: check you handler code is it writing data using this statement : HttpContext.Current.Response.Write to write data in ProcessRequest function everything else is fine

Comment: also check for the elementid i.e element with this id exists or not

Comment: the element with the id exists, and the handler is also writing data using the statement context.Response.Write("<html><body><table style='width:100%;'> ")...


is it because i m using html in the context.response.write?

Comment: have no idea about this but in my application i am just returning url i.e writing url form the handler

Comment: ok one question ... if i do pass some querystring parameters in the str variable ... it shd be in this format 

str = "?abc=xyz";

so tht when the url + str is executed it becomes "http://mysitename.com/myhandler.ashx?abc=xyz" 

... right? basically i m asking we do have to use the question mark to identify the querystrings from the url... sorry its a basic question bt since u jst concatenated both the variables i was thinking why dont we use the complete url (with the querystring parameters) in jst one variable i.e. url...

Comment: yes its correct you can pass query string data in str parameter str = "?abc=xyz";

Answer (score 2):

You can use XMLHttpRequest (AJAX, not necessarily using XML) to load an URL in the background.
I'd highly suggest you to do it through a javascript framework like jQuery since that saves you from accessing the ugly low-level interface directly.

Answer (score 1):

First of please elaborate a bit what are you trying to do.

You can call it with AJAX and request the webservice URL.

Comment: thank you ... actually i didnt ever do it earlier so i wanted a sample code segment :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        saveCookies('true');
    });

function saveCookies(save) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Handlers/getMyData.ashx.ashx",
            data: { 'savecookies': save },
           async: false,
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {   
            }
        });
    };
```